# Bash: Check for specific character in String and add escape character in front of it

Tags: bash, unix

I'm writing a Unix script to export Oracle dmp files which takes in some values fetched from database and form the query string such as below:

```
exp $USER/$DBPASSWD@$ORACLE_SID file=CARD_TABLE.dmp tables=CARD_TABLE statistics=none query=\"where customer_idno=\'$bsccstid\'\"
```

The value of `$bsccstid` could contain brackets, for example *VIP-1220(A)* and makes the exp command failed to work. May I know how should I check for the brackets and put an escape character in front of it?

UPDATE:
Thanks for all the answers here. Sorry if I confused you with my question. My intention is to ask for a solution to add escape character in front of brackets.

```
echo "191-102-6863(A)" | sed 's/(/\\(/g;s/)/\\)/g'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to escape the brackets is by using sed.

```
echo "191-102-6863(A)" | sed 's/(/\\(/g;s/)/\\)/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

A good rule of thumb for shell scripting is to double-quote all variable expansions, unless you need the variable to expand into multiple words. Here's an example of with some minimal changes to your command that quotes all the variables.

```
exp \
    "$USER/$DBPASSWD@$ORACLE_SID" \
    file=CARD_TABLE.dmp \
    tables=CARD_TABLE \
    statistics=none \
    query="\"where customer_idno='$bsccstid'\""
```

Comment: Actually in this script, I'll echo many of these exp commands into another script and execute it.

Such as:
`echo "exp $USER/$DBPASSWD@$ORACLE_SID file=CARD_TABLE.dmp tables=CARD_TABLE statistics=none query=\\\"where cb_customer_idno\\\=\\\'$bsccstid\\\'\\\"" >> $WORKING_DIR/temp.sh
echo "exp $USER/$DBPASSWD@$ORACLE_SID file=CARD_OPT.dmp tables=CARD_OPT statistics=none query=\\\"where individual_acctno in $expindlist\\\"" >> $WORKING_DIR/temp.sh`
 
How should I achieve it using your sample?

Comment: Do you have to use bash to generate the script? If you have several lists of input files that you're trying to assemble into a standalone script it might be easier to generate the script using awk or perl or python or something.

Comment: This is starting to look like an x/y problem.  Why on earth you would be doing such complicated echoes seems a bit overboard.  Surely if you are intending on placing them in a file you would simply open the file and edit as needed?  it looks like you should actually write a script (as advised above in any language) to generate your lines as needed.

Comment: Actually this is a temporary script used in current production system. We have someone working on the Java version but now we need to urgently solve the brackets issue.

Comment: @ReginaFoo The problem is bad quoting. Your script in the initial question is mostly fine except that you're missing double quotes around the `query=...` argument. If you replace `query=\"where customer_idno=\'$bsccstid\'\"` with `"query=\"where customer_idno=\'$bsccstid\'\""`, then the quoting will be correct (assuming that bsccstid doesn't contain `'`, but that's another matter)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible example of how you might attack this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

bsccstid="VIP-1220(A)"
bsccstid=${bsccstid//(/\\(}
bsccstid=${bsccstid//)/\\)}
expindlist="('blah')"

tables=(CARD_TABLE CARD_OPT)
query=( "where cb_customer_idno = '$bsccstid'"
                "where individual_acctno in $expindlist"
            )

for t in "${!tables[@]}"
do
    echo exp $USER/$DBPASSWD@$ORACLE_SID file="${tables[t]}.dmp" tables="${tables[t]}" statistics=none query="${query[t]}"
done
```

Assuming the output looked accurate on running the above, you could then simply remove the echo and exp command would actually run